# Comprobar recyclerview vacío

Tags: android, kotlin

Quiero comprobar si el recyclerview que he creado está vacío o no, y en función de eso mostrar u ocultar un textview. Estoy tomando los datos de Firebase y este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

Adaptador:

```
class FichasAdapter(var dataSet: Array<Ficha>, val activity: AppCompatActivity) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FichasAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    /**
     *  indicamos la referencia del tipo de vista que estamos usando
    */
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val botonDetalleCoche: Button
    init {
        // Definimos clicklistener para el viewholder
        botonDetalleCoche = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDetallecoche)
    }
}
// Creamos una vista con el Viewholder
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    // Creamos una vista, que está definida por la lista de items
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.celda_ficha, viewGroup, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)

}
// Reemplazamos los contenidos de la vista
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // Obtenemos los elementos del database en esta posicion y reemplazamos los contenidos de la vista
    viewHolder.botonDetalleCoche.text = dataSet[position].nombre
    viewHolder.botonDetalleCoche.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this.activity, ActivityForm::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("idFicha", dataSet[position].id)
        this.activity.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
// Devuelve el tamaño del dataset
override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
```

}

Clase "ficha":

```
class Ficha {
var id : String = ""
var nombre : String = ""
```

}

Activity:

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.lista_fichas)
    val datos = listOf<Ficha>().toTypedArray()
    val adaptador = FichasAdapter(datos, this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adaptador
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    //obtiene los registros de la coleccion Fichas
    db.collection(coleccionFichas).addSnapshotListener { snapShot, _ ->

        val nombres = snapShot?.documents?.map {
            val ficha = Ficha()
            ficha.id = it.id
            ficha.nombre = it.data?.get("nombre")?.toString() ?: ""
            ficha
        }?.toTypedArray()
        nombres?.let {
            adaptador.dataSet = it
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

He probado a crear un if tomando como condición recyclerView.adapter!=null pero no funciona, ¿Como debo realizar el if para sepa si existen fichas creadas en el recyclerView y que si no existen ninguna se muestre el textView y si existen se muestre? Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Ya tienes el método en el adapter:

```
 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataSet.size
}
```

En la activity con un `if` preguntas si es igual a cero:

```
 adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()
 if(adaptador.itemCount ==0){
            textView.setText("vacio")
        }else{
            textView.setText("")
        }
```

Usa el método `isEmpty` dentro de la activity, en caso de que uses un `BaseAdapter (getCount())`:

```
 if (adaptador.isEmpty){
        textView.setText("vacio")
    }else{
        textView.setText("")
    }
```

Comment: Buenas Armen, gracias por la respuesta. He probado a insertar tu código dentro de la activity en el oncreate() pero el método isEmpty no lo encuentra. En qué parte de la activity debería colocarlo exactamente?

Comment: También he probado a insertarlo a continuación del código aportado en la activity con el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo con el siguiente código:

```
if (nombres.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                textViewSinFichas1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                textViewSinFichas2.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
```